# Does it matter that Netgear R7000 is not Wi-Fi certified?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I'm considering to get an AC1900 router for my house and it looks like Asus RT-68U and Netgear R7000 are the most favourites to many reviewers.

However, I read the Netgear hardware usually is not Wi-Fi certified. I'm not sure what does it mean in general, but should I be worried that it might not works with some devices? (like PS4, TV, etc...)?

Comment: It has to be certified otherwise Netgear wouldn't be allowed to sell it in the US or an EU country.  Does not really matter, the router in question, [actually is certified](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/datasheet/en/R7000.pdf).  It is literally illegal to sell a device like the R7000 unless its been certified.

Comment: @Ramhound It is not certified according to http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-reviews/32239-ac1900-first-look-netgear-r7000-a-asus-rt-ac68u

Comment: I provided you the official manual for the product  The device is certified.  The review is not accurate.